# 100% height on flexbox child breaks when loading as Angular2 component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, angular, flexbox

So... I'm creating a dashboard using Angular2 and Bootstrap V4 and I've been banging my head against a wall for what seems 6 hours!

http://www.codeply.com/go/btVTVaz1ah

As you can see from the above example, I have recreated the DOM structure and all works nicely, however when loading the structure via Angular2, it goes all wrong.

[image: Broked!]

https://embed.plnkr.co/ccHxQdYZ8iY2XjJ7am7h/

For some strange reason, the 100% height on the bootstrap .card when loaded via Angular inherits it's height from the viewport and not it's parent like in my codeply above.

I'm sure it's just a simple fix, for those with fresh eyes!

Comment: This *may* be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276 .. Being that it seems to be an Angular, not a browser, issue, it may not help. But some of the workarounds in my answer may help you identify the problem.